# The police or police

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, zero-article

> He must have called the police.

OR

> He must have called police.

I think we use the first one when we know about a specific group of police officers which we have called and the second one, when, we talk about any police group which we don't specifically know.

Am I correct?

Answer (score -1):

I would say "the police."

I think the only time I would not put "the" before "police" is if "police" is the subject at the beginning of the sentence or phrase.